# Blueprinted pages in one publication are deleted when published in a sibling publication

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

Given a Blueprint structure:

> 400 Branded Site Master
>
> > 500 Branded Site A
> >
> > 500 Branded Site B

with pages created at the 400 level and specific Components localized at 500 (e.g. "contact us" for a specific brand).  All these publications are using the same deployer, with different directories specified in their publication data.

We are facing the following unusual situation:

- When contact_us.xhtml is published from 600 Branded Site B, it is deleted from 600 Branded Site A
- When contact_us.xhtml is published from 600 Branded Site A, it is deleted from 600 Branded Site B

The problem here - to be clear - is that publishing from either publication should not delete a file from the filesystem of the other publication!

The deployer configuration here is:

```xml
<Storages>
    <StorageBindings/>
    <Storage Type="filesystem"
        Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory"
        Id="filesystem"
        defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="/path/to/deployment/directory"/>
    </Storage>
    <Storage Type="filesystem"
        Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory"
        Id="data"
        defaultStorage="true"
        defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="/path/to/deployment/directory/data"/>
    </Storage>
</Storages>
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="data" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="filesystem"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"
        itemExtension=".Jsp"
        cached="false"
        storageId="filesystem"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="filesystem"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

Tridion in this case is outputting flat HTML content, which are essentially file includes for an application.  There are no dynamic links, everything is flat, static, traditional pages, i.e. target language="none".  And because of that, it was deemed - by the third party developers - that there was no need for a database.

I can resolve the issue (in dev) by using a database as default storage, but there won't be one in production for this set of sites.

Tridion version is 2011 and is using the Java CDE.  Is there anything obviously wrong in this configuration / set up? It seems an "unusual" behaviour for what seems to be an allowed configuration!

Comment: Just to clarify - when you say it is 'deleting' do you mean it's overwriting - or are these is different folders and the file in the alternate publication / physical folder is being removed?

Comment: It's the latter.  If I publish "Brand A" then files appear in `brand_a/pages`.  If I publish the same files in "Brand B", then files appear in `brand_b/pages` and `brand_a/pages` disappears from the filesystem.

Comment: Per your question"with pages created at the 400 level"; Are you having Pages created in the "400 Branded Site Master Layer"? Are the same pages localized too in the 600 layer? If pages are created in the master layer, what happens if you publish 400 layer with "Also Publish/Unpublish to child publications" during publishing?

Comment: Odd indeed Dave. You've no event system code running in the background that could be 'tidying up'? If you physically remove the file - is there anything in the logs to indicate 'file not found to delete'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it might be related to the defaultFilesystem flag in the cd_Storage_conf.xml. 
The standard sample of the cd_Storage_conf.xml has one location set to true for this flag. This flag creates a folder per publication and so separating the pages/items per publication.

Comment: This could be it. The only way I can think of this happening is if the metadata is telling Tridion that it is the same page - which would happen if the metadata is all stored in the same location, without a "publication separator". Worth testing for sure, check the default storage config.

Comment: Yes, this was it.  Thanks.  For reference, the issue was fixed by changing the defaultFilesystem attribute to `defaultFilesystem="true"` and removing `defaultStorage="true"` from the second `<Storage>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you don't want both of these publications to publish to the same place, so I'm assuming that you want these to publish to:

- /path/to/deployment/directory/500 Branded Site A/
- /path/to/deployment/directory/500 Branded Site B/

Is that correct?

If so, have you checked that the `Publication Path` and `Images Path` settings are different for each of your sites (500 Branded Site A & 500 Branded Site B) within the publication properties?

[image]

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks - I did have to double check, but the publication path and images paths are set differently for each publication (as `\path\to\{brandname}` and `\path\to\{brandname}\images`, respectively)